# NewtonSoft JsonConvert SerializeObject Dictionary of Object Escape Chars

Tags: c#, json, wcf, dictionary, json.net

I'm having some trouble using the JsonConvert.SerializeObject method concerning escape chars in WCF. My web method returns a Stream as follows:

```
 return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)));
```

This works fine apart from one of the properties of myObject is a Dictionary of `<string, object>`. All of the simple types serialize correctly, however when I try and add my custom class as a value I get the type returned instead of the data. On realising this comes from the serialiser calling .ToString on my custom class I've tried overriding it with:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
```

However the returned data now includes escape chars

```
{       
    "my_dictionary":    {
      "elem_1": "{\"Prop1\":null,\"Prop2\":3}",
      "elem_2": "{\"Prop1\":null,\"Prop2\":3}",
      "int_property" : 123
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how I could avoid my custom class being escaped in this way and returned as an array?

Thanks in advance, Matt

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaScriptSerializer (just replace "Object" with your custom class)

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

List<Object> list = new List<Object>();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string res = jss.Serialize(list);
```

and get this format with "res" value:

```
[{"IdEmpresa":1,"Nombre":"Test","URL":"http:/localhost:8080/","Activo":true},IdEmpresa":2,"Nombre":"Test2,","URL":"http://localhost:8081/","Activo":true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've realised there was a mistake in the code. The class that was being serialised actually returned a Dictionary the conversion of the object to a string was causing the behaviour I'd observed and in reality the serializer was perfectly able to serialise the objects correctly.